# How do I get Flood Filled area on python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, flood-fill

There is a library on python does flood fill, the `PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill` function colors some part of the image using Flood Fill algorithm.

[image]

I want to write python application that allows me to write some memo about specific area on the map. The map input will be an image, if you click an area on the map, a window will pop up so you can write a memo about the area.

The problem occurs when you try to get memos written about particular area. I want to implement the program to show all memos related to clicked area.

To do this, I decided to save memos with its coordinate information so I can select it with flood fill algorithm. in order to do this, I have to flood fill to **select** the area, not **color** the area.

The term **select** means watching some area so you can decide whether or not a coordinate is inside of the area.

So what should I do to **select** the area? are there any further improvements on my program design?

Comment: If polygons can be created that represent the filled areas, there are fairly standard "point-in-polygon" algorithms available that could used to determine which area a given point is inside of (if any). This is a fairly common need in graphical applications. You can try searching for "hit-detection". It's also similar to object-collision detection techniques.

Comment: @martineau I really appreciate your comment but then there is an another problem. How do you create polygon out of the filled area? I think this would be the root problem of my question. are thre any other known algorithm or library does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to detect contours with [this post](http://freeconnection.blogspot.com/2013/07/vectorize-image-with-python-scikit-image.html) solution. Then we can just traverse all contours list and check if click coords is in some polygon.

Comment: Congratulations. Glad to hear you solved your follow-on question and got something working. This basic functionaity should allow you create even more interactive graphical applications.

Comment: @martineau Absolutely. Thank you.